# Convert a paragraph into sentences with dynamic memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc, text-segmentation

How can I convert a paragraph into sentences? I have a function signature as follows:

```
char **makeSentences(char *paragraph);
```

In which:

- `paragraph` is a string containing several sentences. Paragraph ensures that each sentence ends with a period (.) and the whole paragraph ends with a null-terminator.
- returns a dynamically allocated array of sentences.

I'm a bit confused of how to allocate the memory for the array of sentences on the fly.

Comment: How is caller supposed to know how many sentences will be returned by the function?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my question.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `malloc` and `realloc`. Have you tried to use these facilities?

Comment: It's all to do with malloc and realloc, but I still have no clue how can I allocate memory (for a new chacter or a sentence) on the fly :)

Comment: I meant how is **caller**, not callee supposed to know how many sentences will be returned by the function?

Comment: Not all sentences end with a period.  Do you realise that some sentences end with a question mark?  Hell, some questions even end with an exclamation mark!

Comment: So? I told you that is a restriction in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Within `makeSentences` you will need to examine `paragraph` to determine the number of characters each sentence contains, including the period and a character for `\0`.

You can allocate the memory like this:

```
int i;
char** sentences = (char**)malloc( sizeof(char*) * number_of_sentences );
for (i = 0; i < number_of_sentences; i++) {
    sentences[i] = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * length_of_sentences[i] );
}
```

where `length_of_sentences` is an array containing the sentence lengths you've discovered.

Comment: But how do I manage to copy each character into the sentence array?

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper method to provide a count for the number of paragraphs in advance, and then malloc an array of char* pointers based on this number. It will be something like this although the below code is untested so it might not work straight off:

```
int getSentenceCount( char* paragraph) {
   int sentenceCount = 0, i = 0;
   for(i=0; i < sizeof(paragraph); i++){
        if(paragraph[i] == '.') sentenceCount++;
   }

   return sentenceCount;
}
```

Once you've got a sentence count the rest should be easy using string utility functions (See string.h)

Answer (score 0):

So that the caller can determine when it reached the end of the array, just make the array one entry larger and use NULL for the last/extra entry.

The hard part is definitely going to be determining where sentences start/end. Here's some example sentences (one sentence per line):

```
Hello world!
Are you hungry?
She said "Hello. I'm Sara!" and smiled.
I installed version 1.3.
They laughed at the F.B.I. and ran.
The function returned the sequence 1, 3, 5, ..., 33.
7 is a lucky number (and this sentence doesn't start with a capital letter).
```

Put all these sentences into a single paragraph to see if your "end of sentence" detection works correctly.